# Swift UITableView: How to remove space under the last cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a normal UITableView with two cells. Every cell has a height of `view.frame.size.height - 250` in the `heighForRowAt` method.
But under the last cell a white space appears. [Look:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dds1b.png)

But I would like that it is  [like that:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCUTi.png)

Does anyone know how to do this?
Warm greetings

PS: The bottom constraint of my tableview is 0 = superview

Comment: That is the safe area. run your code on iPhone 8 and you will find out

Comment: @BenPython Align the bottom constraint of table view with the superview, not with the safearea, constant value should be 0. + set `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` to `.never`

Comment: Thanks for your Answers! The bottom constraint of my tableview is 0 = superview

Comment: @BenPython do u still see white space at the bottom??

Answer (score 1):

- Add tableview bottom constraint with superview rather than with Safe Area.
- The issue is because of tableview bottom constraint with Safe Area.

Comment: In case you are constraining the view yourself: use the bottomAnchor instead of the safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but the bottom constraint ist already to the bottom of the superview. I see it also in my tableView when i scroll up.

Comment: Hi, check is your view.frame.size is same to your screen size or different

Comment: Yes it is. I just looked how my app works with an iPhone 8 and by an iPhone 8 the space isn´t there. I think the space under the cell ist only by an iPhone with a notch and also with round Corners. I now added a function that checks wich iPhone the user has and than set the tableview bottom anchor to + 40. And it worked!